# Testing Struts application: token handling

Tags: jmeter, struts-1

I'm using JMeter to test a Struts application that uses the `saveToken` and `isTokenValid` mehods.

I have a page to select a list of items and then a page to update 1 of the items. When token is set going to the update page, but somehow it changes when I submit the form.  Any Ideas?

Note: I follow the same path with the JMeter test as I do within the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've done to overcome the formToken problem in our app:

Duplicate the HTTP request. Remove all parameters, and turn it into a GET. Place it before your original request (the POST), and add a regex to the GET, retrieving the token. In the original POST, reference the token as a variable.

The tree would look like this:

```
. . .
GET 
+ Regex for Token
POST
. . .
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In [jmeter archives](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/how-to-use-org-apache-struts-action-TOKEN-in-JMeter-td514608.html) I found the regex you need to use to take the token from first response and add it to next sampler:

```
name="org\.apache\.struts\.taglib\.html\.TOKEN".*?value="(.*?)"
```